# DirectX 11 models with even indices not rendered

Tags: directx, directx-11

I have a problem with directx 11 rendering - if i try to render more then one model, i see just models with odd index. All model that are rendered with even index are not visible.

my code based on rastertek tutorials:

```
m_dx->BeginScene(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
{
    m_camera->Render();

    XMMATRIX view;
    m_camera->GetViewMatrix(view);

    XMMATRIX world;
    m_dx->GetWorldMatrix(world);

    XMMATRIX projection;
    m_dx->GetProjectionMatrix(projection);

    XMMATRIX ortho;
    m_dx->GetOrthoMatrix(ortho);

    world = XMMatrixTranslation(-2, 0, -4);
    m_model->Render(m_dx->GetDeviceContext());
    m_texture_shader->Render(m_dx->GetDeviceContext(), m_model->GetIndicesCount(), world, view, projection,
        m_model->GetTexture());

    world = XMMatrixTranslation(2, 0, -2);
    m_model->Render(m_dx->GetDeviceContext());
    m_texture_shader->Render(m_dx->GetDeviceContext(), m_model->GetIndicesCount(), world, view, projection,
        m_model->GetTexture());

    world = XMMatrixTranslation(0, 0, -3);
    m_model->Render(m_dx->GetDeviceContext());
    m_texture_shader->Render(m_dx->GetDeviceContext(), m_model->GetIndicesCount(), world, view, projection,
        m_model->GetTexture());

}
m_dx->EndScene();
```

Model render method

```
UINT stride, offset;

stride = sizeof(VertexPosTextureNormal);
offset = 0;

device_context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertex_buffer, &stride, &offset);
device_context->IASetIndexBuffer(m_index_buffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
device_context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
```

Shader render method:

```
world = XMMatrixTranspose(world);
view = XMMatrixTranspose(view);
projection = XMMatrixTranspose(projection);

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped_subres;
RETURN_FALSE_IF_FAILED(context->Map(m_matrix_buffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mapped_subres));
MatrixBuffer* data = (MatrixBuffer*)mapped_subres.pData;
data->world = world;
data->view = view;
data->projection = projection;
context->Unmap(m_matrix_buffer, 0);
context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &m_matrix_buffer);
context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture);

    // render
    context->IASetInputLayout(m_layout);

context->VSSetShader(m_vertex_shader, NULL, 0);
context->PSSetShader(m_pixel_shader, NULL, 0);
context->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_sampler_state);
context->DrawIndexed(indices, 0, 0);
```

What can be the reason of this?

thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say odd index and even index.

Comment: for example, i render first time, change world matrix, render second time, change world matrix, render third time. second render is not visible

Comment: Is this bit of code :- world = XMMatrixTranspose(world); view = XMMatrixTranspose(view); projection = XMMatrixTranspose(projection); transposing the matrices each time you call it so that they get flipped each time and so only work alternate times? If so, transport into a different variable or just do it once?

Comment: When i store transposed matrices in new variables all renders nice! Thank you very much. But really i don't understand this behavior - i send matrix as XMMATRIX& param to render function, then this matrix transposed, yep. But then i create new matrix with XMMatrixTranslation, even in same variable, and send her to next render.. so why it affects him? MatrixBuffer already have correct transposed matrix, isn't it?

Comment: You are doing that for your world matrix, but your view and projection matrices look like you are passing a reference to the same one each time.

Comment: Yes it's true, i really forgot about them. thank you again.

Comment: Also this is marked c# but looks like c++ to me...

Comment: Why has the answer been deleted by a moderator and then added to this as a comment, and then a note about avoiding extended comments been added. It makes no sense.

Comment: it really confusing. also "C#" tag was added to question, and i had to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code -

```
world = XMMatrixTranspose(world);
view = XMMatrixTranspose(view);
projection = XMMatrixTranspose(projection);
```

is transposing the same matrixes each time you call it so they only have the correct value alternate times. The world matrix is being reset each time in the calling code but the view and project matrices are wrong alternate times.